# Is this chord in Für Elise an example of a diminished seventh chord in classical music?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony

We seem to think that some of those 'far-out' seventh chords are only the remit of jazz music but you can as I understand it add a fourth note to any of the diatonic chords in standard harmony to make a seventh-chord.

Is the following example from 'Für Elise' an example of a Diminished seventh chord built on the leading tone note of a minor, used as a cliffhanger to really superb effect.

[image]

Link to the score [here.](http://hz.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/9/90/IMSLP51818-PMLP14377-Beethoven_Werke_Breitkopf_Serie_25_No_298_WoO_59_Fuer_Elise.pdf)

Comment: Diminished seventh chords are extremely common in classical music. An example like the one you’re posting isn’t even chromatic; it’s just the standard form of the vii°7, in the most common inversion no less.

Comment: **E**-(L)-(I)-**S**-**E**... https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80263/f%C3%BCr-elise-opening-motif

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, it is! G♯ is the root, and B, D, and F are the third, fifth, and seventh, respectively.

Notice that, since B is in the bass, this is in first inversion, so it's a vii°<sup>6/5</sup>. As it often the case with the vii°<sup>6/5</sup>, it resolves to tonic in first inversion so that the diminished fifth `B–F` can resolve inward, with the B resolving up the tonic's chordal third of C.

This is by no means uncommon in tonal music of the Common-practice period. Whoever "we" is that thinks it's only the remit of jazz is missing out on a lot of fully diminished seventh chords! They were used consistently long before Bach.

Comment: And then there was an entire section on common-tone diminished seventh chords I got from my music theory classes. (They're most commonly found in Romantic-era music, from my experience, and they do not resolve like the others.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci Make that an answer please that sounds very interesting.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Maybe it would be best to ask another question?

Answer (score 2):

as Pat says in his comment: the dim 7 chords are very common in classic music

1. as substitution of the V to the tonic (as in your example)
2. as (vii°7) to any step of the scale (in all inversions) 
   -> Bach's prelude 1 in C
3. for modulation from on key to another 
   (as VII° leading to the I 46 of the new tonic:

   example:

a) C F G C cadence than modulation C - c minor - c-dim7 - Db

b) C am F dm D#° Am/E E7 Am

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.  It is G♯dim7/B.  In Roman numerals, we write as vii<sup>o6/5</sup>.

---

Diatonic seventh chords of A minor:

- Am(maj7)/C
- Bm7(♭5)/D
- Caug(maj7)/E
- Dm7/F
- E7/G♯
- Fmaj7/A
- ***G♯dim7/B***

Comment: This doesn't add anything new that the other answers don't already say.